# Calculating the dimension of a Matrix vector space where sum of all rows and columns is 0

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to calculate the dimension of a vector space, and came up with two different answers.

Let $V$ be a Matrix vector space of all $3x3$ matrices over field $\mathbb R $, where the sum of each row and column is 0.

Two different approaches gave me different answers, where:

1. Each matrix follows the rule: $\begin{bmatrix}a&b&-a-b\\c&d&-c-d\\-a-c&-b-d&a+b+c+d\end{bmatrix}$.

That means each element can be described by 4 variables, so $dim V=4$

2. Each matrix follows the rule: $\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{bmatrix}$

Therefore, $a+b+c = 0, d+e+f = 0,g+h+i=0,a+d+g=0,b+e+h=0, c+f+i=0$

The equations give us the following matrix :
$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&1&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1\\1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0\\0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0\\0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

The reduced echelon form is of $\rho(A)=5$

Doesn't that mean that $dim V=5$?

Thanks for answering!

Comment: But once again, if you reach the reduced echelon form, you find out there are 5 locked variables. Then there's a difference between the first approach to the second approach.

Comment: No, obviously not. You are already solving all six equations like in 1., right? How did you found out $5$? This appears to be mysterious and without proof.

Comment: I edited the issue. You're right. But please look at this link, added below. This is the reduced echelon form of the matrix.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfdVR.png

Comment: Consider the equations I added, they make the following matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&1&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1\\1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0\\0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0\\0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

I added in the link the echelon form of the matrix.

Comment: Note $5= 9-4{}$

Comment: You are looking for the size of the solution space to the equation $Mx = 0$. So, you're not counting the pivot variables (which I think you call "locked variables"), you're counting the free variables

Comment: Ah, I understand. What  I'm looking for is the dimension of the vector space which solves $Mx = 0$, or basically $dim(V) = n - \rho(A)$. Which means $dim(V) = 9 - 5 = 4$.
I study in a language other than English, so I'm not always sure if I'm using the right terms. Thank you for your answer!